# Can't find my error in solving $\int \cos^2x \sin 2x \space dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I was asked to solve

$$\int \cos^2x \sin 2x \space dx$$

I solved it using the identity $\cos^2x = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2x))$ and the substitution $u = 2x$.

$$\int \cos^2x \sin 2x \space dx = \frac{1}{2}\int(1+\cos2x)\sin2x \space dx$$
$$ \frac{1}{4} \int (\sin u + \sin u \cos u) \space du \tag{$u = 2x$}$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}(\cos u + \int t \space dt) \tag{$t = \sin u$}$$
$$=\frac{\cos 2x}{4} + \frac{\sin^2 2x}{8} + C$$

I can't find an error in my procedure. However, the correct answer is supposed to be $-\frac{1}{2}\cos^4 x + C$. I did the problem a few times to make sure I was not missing anything, and couldn't find a problem in my logic. Since there clearly is one, I was hoping someone could point it out to me and show me the correct approach to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\int^x \sin(u)\,\mathrm d u=-\cos(x)+C$ and $\int^x \cos(u)\sin(u)\,\mathrm d u=\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)+C$

Comment: $$\int t\,dt=t^2/2=\sin^2 2x/2.$$

Comment: @Surb that was a typo in Latex, my actual answer did have $sin^2 x$. Sorry about that. I corrected it, but still looks nothing like what I should be getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get:$$\int\sin(u)\,du =-\cos u+C=-\cos(2x)+C.$$
You lost the minus sign.

So your closed form, without your constant, is $$\frac{-\cos 2x}4+\frac{\sin^2 2x}8=\frac{-2\cos(2x)+1-\cos^2(2x)}8=\frac{2-(\cos(2x)+1)^2}{8}$$

Then substitute $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x-1,$ and you get $$\frac{2-4\cos^4x}{8}=-\frac{\cos^2 x}{2}+\frac14,$$ which differs from the given answer by a constant.

So your approach works to give an equivalent correct answer, but you needed to fix the two integral you used.

Comment: I did get the square of $sin$ in my actual answer, I just comitted a typo in Latex. Sorry about that. I already corrected it. The answer still doesn't look like what I should be getting. And I believe there is a typo in your answer as well, since one of the formulas is not showing (you skipped a '$' symbol). Thank you.

Comment: The negative sign totally my miss. Thanks!!

Comment: @lafinur edited to remove the first correction, and only include the sign correction.